# How to draw ellipse correctly [KineticJs]

Tags: html, javascript, javascript-framework, kineticjs

how could i create a drawing canvas that can create an ellipse based on the mouse coordinates?
here's my code on jsfiddle (i'm still new to this one) :

http://jsfiddle.net/thekucays/DRfph/

here's my code to draw the ellipse (line 59):

```
var x, y, width, height;
        //var rect;

        //Math.min untuk mencari nilai terkecil dari 2 parameternya
        x = Math.min(event.clientX, lastX);
        y = Math.min(event.clientY, lastY);

        //Math.abs buat bikin nilai negatif jadi positif
        width = event.clientX - lastX;
        height = event.clientY - lastY;

        if(rect_drawed == 0){
            rect = new Kinetic.Ellipse({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                radius:{
                    x: width,
                    y: height
                },
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 4,
                fill: 'blue',
                name: 'rect'+rect_counter
            });
            layer.add(rect);
            layer.draw();
            rect_drawed = 1;
            //stage.add(rect);

            /*rect.on('click', function(){
                rect.setFill('RED');
            });*/
        }
        rect.setAttrs({
            x: width / 2,
            y: height / 2
        });
        layer.draw();
```

so, when i execute the code, it will result to an error..chrome's console said : 
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1 on kinetic.js:29

what went wrong with my code?

Best Regards,

Luki R Rompis

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code,

```
    width = event.clientX - lastX;
    height = event.clientY - lastY;
```

You are allowing width and height to be negative, which throws your DOM exception.

Make it:

```
    width = Math.abs(event.clientX - lastX);
    height = Math.abs(event.clientY - lastY);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HSdgT/3/ This link replicates your error.

http://jsfiddle.net/HSdgT/4/ This link is with the error gone.